# Excel: I need the VBA to Display Text When An Image Is Clicked

Tags: excel, vba

Can I ask the VBA code to display text when I click an image in Excel.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

That's really simple.

1. Right click the image and select assign macro
2. type `activesheet.range("A1") = "my text"` Within the `sub`

`activesheet.range("A1") = "my text"` This would create text `my text` on the active worksheet at Cell A1. You can play around and modify the values according to your needs.

You might want to consider search on Search Engine first before posting.

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm currently finding same as this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TKQWgMdVjQI. I'm finding on Search Engine but cannot find. I want to click on the image and the text will appear on 1 cell of worksheet. Glad that you help :D

Comment: modify the answer above to execute `activesheet.range("A1") = "my text"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Sub Image1_Click()

'A1 is the cell where you want your text to appear
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value = "image clicked"

End Sub
```